# Ways to Weight a Vector

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have vectors resembling the following:

1) 001010010
2) 100100100
3) 111000000
4) 010010100

Is there a way to weight each vector depending on how close together the 1s are, perhaps by either using a gaussian or boxcar-like function? (i.e. Vectors with 1s that are close together would have a higher number attached to it)

Comment: Are these provided to you as strings or integers?  Also, do the samples provided to you follow a normal distribution?

Comment: @MichaelSmith As integers, and I'm not entirely but I think they do

Comment: So is this the binary representation of the number, or is the number only a series of 0's and 1's?

Comment: @MichaelSmith Each vector only contains 0's and 1's, it doesn't represent a number. I'd like to find an arbitrary way to weight each of these vectors which greater weights attached to vectors where 1s are closer compared to smaller weights when 1s are further apart.